# Docker PHP Addons E: Package 'php-json' has no installation candidate

Tags: php, docker

Today I tried to install some PHP extensions for the default php docker container. My dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM php:7.2-cli
#remove apt install restriction
RUN rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/no-debian-php

#Install php-addons
RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y php-zip php-xml php-json php-mbstring

COPY . /
WORKDIR /
```

I got 2 errors by default.

> Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
>     Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
>   Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'

AND

> E: Package 'php-json' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 0):

The Solution to this was:

> E: Package 'php-json' has no installation candidate

fixed with this line in dockerfile

```
RUN rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/no-debian-php
```

AND

> Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
>     Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
>   Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'

Fixed with

```
Uncomment the following line in /etc/default/docker
DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4"
```

Comment: `RUN rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/no-debian-php` worked. Any idea why?